# How can I hide a subject in subject field, just like hiding an item from optionset field in MS Dynamics CRM 2015?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, xrm

It is easy to remove an option from an option set.

```
 var control = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("casetypecode");
 control.removeOption(1);
```

But, when you try to remove a subject from a subject field, it does not work.

This is the type:

[image]

This is how it looks when expanded:

[image]
Can anybody help about this?

Comment: What are you referring to as a subject field? Is that a text field?

Comment: I added images above

Comment: Ok, what is it you're trying to do? Why do you want to remove subjects? I know that these might be "stupid" questions but sometimes it's easier to come up with a solution when you know what's happening.

Comment: There are old records with the subjects to be deleted. If I delete these subjects, they cannot be reachable for older records.

Answer (score 0):

I just don't think that `removeOption` is going to work the subject field, it isn't an option set field - based on your image it is listed as a lookup.

Given that subject is a special field, I'm not sure which options are open to you. If it behaves like a normal lookup you might be able to use the lookup functions to filter the view.

[Lookup control methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602964.aspx#BKMK_LookupControls)